# Does the JDK contains jdbc api?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sdk

Does the Java Development kit contains the JDBC API in general.

I found for sure that the JDK 1.0.2 does not contain the JDBC API, so the DriverManager class typically isn't found by the Java virtual machine running in the browser.

AND The JDBC API is comprised of two packages: java.sql and javax.sql
You automatically get both packages when you download the Java Platform Standard Edition (Java SE).

I am not sure about this but Java SE is no JDK. still I am not sure if the JDK does not contain the JDBC driver.

Comment: Java SE includes the JRE, and may include the JDK, depending on which edition you download. The JDBC API is part of the JRE. JDK 1.0.2 is *ancient*. Forget everything you read about it, as it's not relevant to todays version of Java, which currently is version 11 (or version 8 for people who haven't upgraded yet).

Comment: Why do you think what was in Java 1.0.2 (1997/1998) is in anyway relevant for the situation in 2019 (Java 8 / 11 / 12)? In any case, the JDK is a **superset** of the JRE, so if the JRE includes something, it is definitely included in the JDK. And neither the JRE nor the JDK include a JDBC driver since Java 8 (before that time it had the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver). JDBC drivers are provided by third parties and **implement** the JDBC API.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. At least as of [Java 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/index.html). From the link,

> The JDBC 3.0 API is comprised of two packages:
>
> the `java.sql` package
>
> the `javax.sql` package, which adds server-side capabilities
>
> You automatically get both packages when you download the JavaTM 2 Platform Standard Edition 5.0 (J2SETM).

I can't remember if there were external dependencies in earlier versions.

As for *still I am not sure if the JDK does not contain the JDBC driver.*

It contains the API; the only JDBC driver it contains (as far as I know) is for [Java DB](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) (Apache Derby rebranded is now included).

Comment: JDBC has been part of Java since Java 1.2 (maybe 1.1). The JDBC 2.0 extension API (javax.sql) was initially separate from Java SE, until JDBC 3.0 (Java 1.4) when it was integrated with Java SE. And Apache Derby (JavaDB) is no longer included (and was only included with the JDK, not the JRE).